# XmlReader IsStartElement in a while loop is repeating the previous line

Tags: c#, while-loop, xmlreader

I have an XML that is structured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report blah blah blah>
  <KeywordPerformanceReportColumns>
    <Column name="GregorianDate" />
    <Column name="AccountId" />
    <Column name="AccountNumber" />
    <Column name="AccountName" />
    <Column name="CampaignId" />
    <Column name="CampaignName" />
    etc....
```

From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982251/xmlreader-readstartelement-causes-xmlexception), I learned to use `IsStartElement` to loop through children of `KeywordPerformanceReportColumns`. I'm getting the behavior where it loops back to the first `Column`, never proceeding to the next child.

**Code**

```
//use xmlreader to read the memorystream
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(memStream))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        reader.ReadStartElement("Report");

        //schema information
        reader.ReadStartElement("KeywordPerformanceReportColumns");

        //columns
        while (reader.IsStartElement("Column"))
        {
            //note interested in whitespace nodes
            bool isWhiteSpace = reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Whitespace;

            if (!isWhiteSpace)
            {
                string columnName = reader.GetAttribute("name");
                Console.WriteLine(columnName);
            }
        }

        reader.ReadEndElement( /* "KeywordPerformanceReportColumns" */ );

        reader.ReadEndElement( /* "Report" */ );
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: screen]

Comment: aren't all of the XML nodes you have in your example endElemnts since they end with the "/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [example you've linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982251/xmlreader-readstartelement-causes-xmlexception) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473251/c-sharp-xmlreader-and-child-nodes) the [ReadToNextSibling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf7w4zx9(v=vs.110).aspx) method is used

```
while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("SubEmptyElement"))
```

and not the [IsStartElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xaxy929c(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 while (reader.IsStartElement("Column"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are never advancing to the next node inside of your while loop, so

```
while (reader.IsStartElement("Column"))
```

is never going to complete if it is entered. You might want something like:

```
while (reader.Read() && reader.IsStartElement("Column"))
```